# Showing $X$ belongs to an exponential family

Tags: statistics

Suppose that we observe $X = (X_1, . . . , X_n)$ consisting of i.i.d. random variables from the
Geometric distribution with unknown parameter $θ$,

Show that $X$ belongs to an exponential family (determine all functions of interest) with sufficient statistic $T(X)$ = $\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^n$ $X_i$.

I know how I would show that a singular $X_i$ is a member, but I am unsure on how to do it for something like $X$. Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

The detail depends on which of the four descriptions of the geometric distribution you are using, though the substance is the same.  For example, let's suppose each $X_i$ can take positive integer values and independently $\mathbb P(X_i=x_i)=(1-\theta)^{x_i-1}\theta = (1-\theta)^{x_i}\frac{\theta}{1-\theta}$

Then

- $\mathbb P(X=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n))=\prod\limits_{i=1}^n \left((1-\theta)^{x_i}\frac{\theta}{1-\theta}\right)$
- which can be written as $(1-\theta)^{\sum x_i}\left(\frac{\theta}{1-\theta}\right)^n$
- or as $\exp\left(\sum x_i\log_e(1-\theta)+n\log_e\left(\frac{\theta}{1-\theta}\right)    \right)$

Now apply your definitions of exponential family and sufficient statistic to answer the question